# Tensorflow keep printing something related to FusedBatchNorm

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection

When I use one model(pb file) to inference, tensorflow prints multiple lines related to FusedBatchNorm, snippet below:

```
Optimizing fused batch norm node name: "FirstStageFeatureExtractor/InceptionV2/InceptionV2/Conv2d_2b_1x1/BatchNorm/FusedBatchNorm"
op: "FusedBatchNorm"
input: "FirstStageFeatureExtractor/InceptionV2/InceptionV2/Conv2d_2b_1x1/Conv2D"
input: "FirstStageFeatureExtractor/InceptionV2/Conv2d_2b_1x1/BatchNorm/gamma"
input: "FirstStageFeatureExtractor/InceptionV2/Conv2d_2b_1x1/BatchNorm/beta"
input: "FirstStageFeatureExtractor/InceptionV2/Conv2d_2b_1x1/BatchNorm/moving_mean"
input: "FirstStageFeatureExtractor/InceptionV2/Conv2d_2b_1x1/BatchNorm/moving_variance"
device: "/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"
attr {
  key: "T"
  value {
    type: DT_FLOAT
  }
}
attr {
  key: "data_format"
  value {
    s: "NHWC"
  }
}
attr {
  key: "epsilon"
  value {
    f: 0.001
  }
}
attr {
  key: "is_training"
  value {
    b: false
  }
}
```

The inference result is OK, but a little bit slow. I don't know what's FusedBatchNorm is , and if this guy slow down the inference speed or not.

I run the model upon Centos 7.2 server with Nvidia Tesla P4(8vCPU, 32G memory, GPU memory is 7G), and, it takes 12 seconds for one image in general(I think it's really slow:-( ).

Regarding training, I use tensorflow object detection and model faster_rcnn_resnet101, here is config file:

```
model {
  faster_rcnn {
    num_classes: 3
    image_resizer {
      keep_aspect_ratio_resizer {
        min_dimension:  670
        max_dimension: 1013
      }
    }
    feature_extractor {
      type: "faster_rcnn_resnet101"
      first_stage_features_stride: 16
    }
    first_stage_anchor_generator {
      grid_anchor_generator {
        height_stride: 16
        width_stride: 16
        scales: 0.25
        scales: 0.5
        scales: 1.0
        scales: 2.0
        aspect_ratios: 0.5
        aspect_ratios: 1.0
        aspect_ratios: 2.0
      }
    }
    first_stage_box_predictor_conv_hyperparams {
      op: CONV
      regularizer {
        l2_regularizer {
          weight: 0.0
        }
      }
      initializer {
        truncated_normal_initializer {
          stddev: 0.01
        }
      }
    }
    first_stage_nms_score_threshold: 0.0
    first_stage_nms_iou_threshold: 0.7
    first_stage_max_proposals: 100
    first_stage_localization_loss_weight: 2.0
    first_stage_objectness_loss_weight: 1.0
    initial_crop_size: 14
    maxpool_kernel_size: 2
    maxpool_stride: 2
    second_stage_box_predictor {
      mask_rcnn_box_predictor {
        fc_hyperparams {
          op: FC
          regularizer {
            l2_regularizer {
              weight: 0.0
            }
          }
          initializer {
            variance_scaling_initializer {
              factor: 1.0
              uniform: true
              mode: FAN_AVG
            }
          }
        }
        use_dropout: false
        dropout_keep_probability: 1.0
      }
    }
    second_stage_post_processing {
      batch_non_max_suppression {
        score_threshold: 0.3
        iou_threshold: 0.6
        max_detections_per_class: 30
        max_total_detections: 30
      }
      score_converter: SOFTMAX
    }
    second_stage_localization_loss_weight: 2.0
    second_stage_classification_loss_weight: 1.0
  }
}
train_config {
  batch_size: 1
  data_augmentation_options {
    random_horizontal_flip {
    }
  }
  optimizer {
    momentum_optimizer {
      learning_rate {
        exponential_decay_learning_rate {
          initial_learning_rate: 0.0003
          decay_steps: 2000
          decay_factor: 0.95
        }
      }
      momentum_optimizer_value: 0.9
    }
    use_moving_average: false
  }
  gradient_clipping_by_norm: 10.0
  fine_tune_checkpoint: "d:/od/tool/faster_rcnn3/model.ckpt"
  from_detection_checkpoint: true
}
train_input_reader {
  label_map_path: "d:/od/project/train_allinone/file/labelmap.pbtxt"
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "d:/od/project/train_allinone/file/tf.record"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got the reason:

Tensorflow on my desktop for training is 1.8 but on the inference server is 1.9.

Sorry for the noise.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the verbose debug output: looks like this was a bug that has been fixed in trunk recently: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/pull/19870

With the fix, the output should only get printed out if the VLOG level is set to 2 or higher.